# Moving Unity GameObject from Scene to Another without moving the UI Canvas or the UI Buttons

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i have tried different many ways to move Gameobject without moving the UI-Buttons to another scene, but it always moves the scene with it's UI

Butoons Are Created and givin there handlers inside OnGUI() Event

i used :
`SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(targetSceneName, LoadSceneMode.Additive);`

i also used :
  `SceneManager.MoveGameObjectToScene(element, targetScene);`

but it still moving The UI Buttons

is there a way to move GameObjects without UI Components ?

Comment: Also, stop using OnGiu (as you have mentioned in the comments).

Comment: is there a solution for this ?

Comment: Stop using OnGui. OnGui is old and deprecated and has been replaced by the UI components.

Comment: mmm, but it has a simple solution for responsive UI Components, then how can you deal with Responsive UI Components?

Comment: That's what [RectTransform](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-RectTransform.html) and [AutoLayout](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UIAutoLayout.html) is for. All UI objects have RectTransforms, the pivot and anchors provide the responsiveness. Autolayout handles arranging items to fit within an available space.

Answer (score 2):

It seems your Canvas is attached to the GameObject your moving. You could destroy the canvas object or canvas components upon import.

```
void DestroyGameObject()
{
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

OR

```
void DestroyComponent()
{
    // Removes the rigidbody from the game object
    Destroy(GetComponent<Rigidbody>());
}
```

You could also try attach your canvas to another object in your initial scene so it isn't attached on import. Hope this helps

Comment: actually,I am adding button Dynamically using OnGUI() Event, I wonder why do these buttons Move with the Scene, it still the same problem

Comment: Could you put an IF statement within the On GUI event that determines the output based on the Scene name ?

Comment: Did That and Still the same Problem